# Using an String variable to reference an ArrayList

Tags: java

Is it possible to use a String to reference an array?

```
for(Entry<String, GameInformation> gameSet : GameInfoPuller.gameMap.entrySet())

  {
     //For each entry put the games key into key and the value into value.
     String key = gameSet.getKey();
     GameInformation value = gameSet.getValue();

     String genreSelect = genreSelect(value);

     genreSelect.add(Item here); <---- is there a way to do this?
  } 


private static String genreSelect(GameInformation value)
{
  String genreValue = "";

//Check each entry for the value of its genre and for each genre put into the corresponding category.

  if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Fantasy"))
  {
     genreValue = "fantasy";
  }
  else if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Historical"))
  {
      genreValue = "historical";
  }
  else if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Sci-Fi"))
  {
        genreValue = "sciFi";
  }
  else if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Horror"))
  {
        genreValue = "horror";
  }
  else if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Sports"))
  {
        genreValue = "sports";
  }
  else if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Real Life"))
  {
        genreValue = "realLife";
  }
  else if(value.getGameGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("Super-Hero"))
  {
        genreValue = "superHero";
  }          
  else
  {
        System.out.println("Game: " + " does not have a genre.");
  }
return genreValue;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This looks like a really flawed design. You can, however, use a Map<String, ArrayList> to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, a "String" cannot be a reference to an "ArrayList" because they are incompatible types.

You can, however, use some techniques to map a string to an "ArrayList" instance. For example:

```
  // Initialization of Map Collection.
  Map<String, ArrayList> stringToArrayListMap = new HashMap<>();
  stringToArrayListMap.put("key for the first array list", new ArrayList());
```

You may also be able to use reflection, but I wont get into that since that is a hack and requiring it probably is an indication of a design smell.

Comment: Can I ask why a java comment was added to the example? If this is some standard in stackoverflow, why is this promoted? Source code comments which describe 1:1 (as is the first statement above) what the code is doing, is an added liability and does not add value. If a comment was needed for the first statement, how is that any different from the second statement--why wouldnt one be needed there also? Of course I am not suggesting one be added there, though, but in code, consistency (including use of comments) is fundamental, so I am wondering why it isnt adhered consistently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. 
You could store your genre as the first item of a `List<String>` and than add further items to that list as needed.